# Method called using annotation '@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)' working as expected, but direct call falls

Tags: java, spring-boot, event-listener, completable-future, threadpoolexecutor

When the method is called by `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`, the expected behavior eventually occurs. But when a direct method call occurs, then the loop inside CompletableFuture repeats only once

```
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void method1() {

        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> pool = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, configproperty.getPipelinethreads()).forEach(i -> pool.add(method2()));
        CompletableFuture.allOf(pool.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))
                .thenRun(() -> {
                    log.info("Delta time - " + calcDeltaTime(timeBegin));
                });
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> method2() {

        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            do {
                List<Entity> entityList = facility.fetchEntityList();

                entityList.forEach(entity -> {

                    performStore(entity);
                });
            } while (proceed.get());
        }, asyncThreadPool);//ThreadPoolTaskExecutor
    }
```

`asyncThreadPool` pool got a capacity also from `configproperty.getPipelinethreads()`

I have tried run it using `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` in controller's method and it working properly, but direct call the controller make it motionless after few iterations in CompletableFuture. Where should I look to find the essence of the problem?

Comment: "When method calls using @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) all is good" what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Thank you, the question body was edited for clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by deleting Completablefuture. I mistakenly believed reuse thread when asyncThreadPool complete its task. In my case I decide don't pass DB operation in another thread and make task inside main thread.